# Coil whine-like noise in screen, Windows Explorer-generated

Tags: windows-7, display, windows-explorer

Edit:

It is a screen speaker noise. The noise changes volume when I change the volume on the screen.

I am running a self-built PC including an Iiyama ProLite B2712HDS screen. From time to time a coil whine-like noise comes out of the screen. If I change the folder that is currently open in Windows Explorer, the noise instantly goes away (and does not come back if I change back to the previous folder).

Any hints would be most welcome, this one is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monitor, operating system and problem are all in the trash been, and have been for a year or more. Should I not delete this question, despite the dire warnings that my account will be blocked from posting, as it will never get an adequate answer now?

Answer (score 0):

Being that you are using a LCD monitor, it is unlikely 'coil whine' like the old CRTs. What you are probably hearing is whine from low-quality capacitors in the LCD driver board vibrating at certain frequencies. Does the sound only appear when the explorer window is full screen or in a certain quadrant of the screen?

If you have a spare monitor, try to replicate it with the spare to try and isolate it to that monitor and rule out possible video card issues.

If it is the monitor, you could try filing a warranty claim or simply replace the monitor.

Comment: I'm not even sure explorer has to be the top window (I always go full screen with every window); I just happened to remember to post a question today. I'll update next time it happens. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes noise is generated due to earthing circuitry (speaking from experience). Try removing earth from the connection by removing the third pin from the power cable and the noise heard should be significantly reduced.

Comment: **WARNING** The earth connection is there for a reason. Disconnecting it is dangerous.

Comment: It is yes, only attempt if you're into trying stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Some windows make a kind of a coil whine, some doesnt, and some does it at a different degree.
Right now i have 4 microsoft word windows openned. Switching between them make the noise come and go, and its not the same strength of sound between windows. If the one that makes more noise have some kind of a change, the noise changes in intensity too and i can really tell.

So, as some above stated, im pretty sure its a capacitor or something. This is an old monitor (viewsonic VX1940w, it doesnt has speakers), that its been a pretty while that i want to change it.

Im commenting this for anyone that has this issue since i havent found much around the internet...
So, to you dude that you are reaching for help... ill say its the capacitors. Doesnt mean its about to break, it can go lots of years but the noise may increase and become unvearable.

Maybe you can change them if you feel confortable soldering stuff, but take a lot of care if you do some electrical.

I repaired this monitor myself years ago, changing some capacitors it burned, when it was out of warranty. I desoldered the ones burnt, went to a electric store, asked for the same, and soldered the new ones and boom, the monitor has worked for me since until today...

Its been at least 5 years after that, so i guess its time to let this buddy go to rest soon.

Hope i have helped anybody.